# Perforce: Get a list of Clients accessed > 280 Days ago from a single user

Tags: perforce

Im trying to piece together a list of "dead clients" for a specific user to mark for archiving.

`p4 -ztag -F "%User% %client% %Access%" -u perforce.user clients | awk '$3 < '"$(date -d "280 days ago" +%s)"' {print $1","$2","strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",$3)}'`

is what I have so far but its outputting ALL the clients instead of just the specified user I want, and isnt outputting the user name of the owner of the clients either.

Comment: Messing around with it still, I managed to get it sorted properly, but it wont filter by date still or filter from p4USER
`p4 -ztag -F "%users% %client% %Access%" clients | sort -k2rn | awk '$3 < '"$(date -d "300 days ago" +%s)"' {print $1","strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",$2)}'`

Comment: `p4 clients -u USER` gets you the clients owned by a particular user.  (Note placement -- before the command name is a global flag that means "auth as this user", after the command name is a command flag that in this case means "filter to this user".  Very different!)

Answer (score 1):

it was all syntax with p4 clients

`p4 -ztag -F "%client% %Access%" clients -u perforce.user | sort -k2rn | awk '$3 < '"$(date -d "300 days ago" +%s)"' {print $1","strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",$2)}'`

`-u perforce.user` has to come after `clients`